# How to access ringtones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

My app that I am currently working on, requires me to make a button that makes the user choose the ringtone to use for the push notification. Now I can't for the life of me get documentation on how my app can show the native ringtone list after tapping on that button ?

Will take any advice/ link/ already posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not change the ringtone for notifications from inside an app - nor can you query all available ringtones of the phone from within an app. The user need to go to the settings and change the ringtone there.

Comment: that seems to be all the answers i get! damn MS should start getting their act together for developers!